# Do PHP 5.5' intl extension and PECL intl package origin from the same source code?

Tags: php, internationalization, icu, intl

Recently I had to move from the PHP 5.5's native intl extension to the intl PECL package for the purpose of keeping intl/ICU up to date. But now I wonder if the behavior of intl code in my PHP code base has remained completely unchanged. My code base makes use of almost every intl class and function, so it's not really feasible to run tests on all of them.

Hence a simple question, do PHP 5.5' intl extension and PECL intl package origin from the same source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The PECL page says:

*"This extension has been bundled with PHP since version 5.3."*

http://pecl.php.net/package/intl